# Undefined Variable that Should Be Defined, but I Overcomplicated it

Tags: python, variables, undefined

I'm very new at Python, and programming in general, so please try not to be frustrated.

I'm to make a program (at a friend's request, he's paying me, so don't judge) that would simplify games like truth or dare by making selection of names/dares random. It was working well when I just made it select a person from a group of two boys and two girls, and then select a random dare from an extensive list my friend created. However, I wanted to make it so you could enter specific names, and decide how many names, instead of selecting persons 1-4. I may have vastly overcomplicated it with commands that I had simply Googled and didn't take the time to understand, and now it gives errors for almost every change I make. Now, it's saying that the variable "boys" is undefined, when I did (at least I think I did) earlier. I think that even when I fix "boys," "girls" will have the same problem. Any and all help you can offer with simplification, rectifying errors, and anything else would be greatly appreciated. I know it's long and complicated, but any help at all would be really phenomenal.

```
import random
print "Now, important note, all answers must be made in quotes. I know, it sucks, but that's the way it is and I cannot change it."

print "Ready? [y/n]"
repeat = input()
while repeat == "y":
    print "Are there any boys playing? [y/n]"
    boys1 = input()
    boys2 = "n"
    boys3 = "n"
    boys4 = "n"
    if boys1 == "n":
        repeat == "n"
    if boys1 == "y":
        print "What is the first boy's name?"
        boy1 = input()
        boy2 = ""
        boy3 = ""
        boy4 = ""
        print "Are there any more?"
        boys2 = input()
        boys3 = "n"
        boys4 = "n"
        if boys2 == "y":
            print "What is his name?"
            boy2 = input()
            boy3 = ""
            boy4 = ""
            print "Are there any more?"
            boys3 = input()
            boys4 = "n"
            if boys3 == "y":
                print "What is his name?"
                boy3 = input()
                boy4 = ""
                print "Are there any more?"
                boys4 = input()
                if boys4 == "y":
                    print "What is his name?"
                    boy4 = input()
                    print "The maximum number of boys is four."

    print "Are there any girls playing? [y/n]"
    girls1 = input()
    girls2 = "n"
    girls3 = "n"
    girls4 = "n"
    if girls1 == "n":
        repeat == "n"
    if girls1 == "y":
        print "What is her name?"
        girl1 = input()
        girl2 = ""
        girl3 = ""
        girl4 = ""
        print "Are there any more?"
        girls2 = input()
        girls3 = "n"
        girls4 = "n"
        if girls2 == "y":
            print "What is her name?"
            girl2 = input()
            girl3 = ""
            girl4 = ""
            print "Are there any more?"
            girls3 = input()
            girls4 = "n"
            if girls3 == "y":
                print "What is her name?"
                girl3 = input()
                girl4 = ""
                print "Are there any more?"
                girls4 = input()
                if girls4 == "y":
                    print "What is her name?"
                    girl4 = input()
                    print "The maximum number of girls is four."

    if not boys1 == "y":
        print "There are no boys. The program cannot work." 
        if not boys2 == "y":
            boys = [boy1]
            if not 'boys3' == "y":
                boys = [boy1, boy2]
                if not boys4 == "y":
                    boys = [boy1, boy2, boy3]
                    if boys4 == "y":
                        boys = [boy1, boy2, boy3, boy4]

    if not girls1 == "y":
        print "There are no girls. Your party sucks."
        if not girls2 == "y":
            girls = [girl1]
            if not girls3 == "y":
                girls = [girl1, girl2]
                if not girls4 == "y":
                    girls = [girl1, girl2, girl3]
                    if girls4 == "y":
                        girls = [girl1, girl2, girl3, girl4]

    print random.sample(boys, 1)
    print "must perform the action on"
    print random.sample(girls, 1)

    actions = ["A very long and extensive list of various actions.", "Each in their own section"]
    print random.sample(actions, 1)

    print "Wanna go again?"
    repeat = input()

input()
```

Comment: You may have better luck trying to simplify things and get each part working and then build on top of them.  The flow of your code is quite messy right now.

Comment: Just checking back: did you understand my solution below? Is there anything I can clarify? If any of the answers helped you, you are expected to pick the best one and tick it as the solution; this rewards people for helping you.

Comment: Ah. Thank you @HughBothwell, I hadn't realized that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interest of showing the OP how much more improved this could be (and even this could be improved but is good as an illustration), I took a couple minutes to simplify things:

```
while True:
    try:
        num_girls = raw_input("Number of girls? ")
        num_girls = int(num_girls)
        if num_girls > 4 or num_girls < 0:
            raise Exception("Number of girls must be between 0 and 4")
        if num_girls == 0:
            print "Your party is going to suck"
        break
    except ValueError as e:
        print "You must enter a number 0-4"
    except Exception as e:
        print e

girls = []
for i in range(num_girls):
    girls.append(raw_input("Name of girl #%d: " % (i + 1)))

while True:
    try:
        num_boys = raw_input("Number of boys? ")
        num_boys = int(num_boys)
        if num_boys > 4 or num_boys < 0:
            raise Exception("Number of boys must be between 1 and 4")
        break
    except ValueError as e:
        print "You must enter a number 1-4"
    except Exception as e:
        print e

boys = []
for i in range(num_boys):
    boys.append(raw_input("Name of boy #%d: " % (i + 1)))
```

Then you can just do your random sampling at the end.

Comment: Thank you so much! This will help me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a restructured version which should be easier to follow:

```
import random
import sys

if sys.hexversion < 0x3000000:
    # Python 2.x
    inp = raw_input
    rng = xrange
else:
    # Python 3.x
    inp = input
    rng = range

def get_yn(prompt):
    while True:
        res = inp(prompt).strip().lower()
        if res in {'y','yes'}:
            return True
        elif res in {'n','no'}:
            return False

def get_int(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(inp(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            pass

def get_str(prompt):
    while True:
        res = inp(prompt).strip()
        if res:
            return res

rand = random.choice

actions = [
    "{boy} must compliment {girl}'s hair",
    "{girl} must admire {boy}'s muscles"
]

def main():
    num_boys  = get_int("How many boys are playing? ")
    num_girls = get_int("How many girls are playing? ")

    if num_boys < 1 or num_boys > 4:
        print("Must be one to four boys.")
    elif num_girls < 1 or num_girls > 4:
        print("Must be one to four girls.")
    else:
        print("Let's get this party started!")
        boys  = [get_str("Name of boy {}: " .format(i)) for i in rng(1, num_boys+1) ]
        girls = [get_str("Name of girl {}: ".format(i)) for i in rng(1, num_girls+1)]

        while True:
            act = rand(actions)
            boy = rand(boys)
            girl = rand(girls)
            print(act.format(boy=boy, girl=girl))

            if not get_yn("Want to continue? "):
                break

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

WELCOME TO PROGRAMMING!  I am so happy to hear you are exploring programming!

Read up on [Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

And also on [Object Oriented Programming (OOP)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm) (In Python (and most languages?) "objects" are usually called: `Classes`

Comment: Despite the recommendation of the site to avoid comments saying, "Thank you," I felt it was necessary to express my sheer gratitude. Thanks you!